# How can I calculate the YoY on cognos 11.1?

Tags: calculation, cognos-11

Is it possible to know somebody how can I calculate/make the `YoY, MoM` filter on **Cognos 11.1** expression editor ??? Mt file has the following structure. Same logic applies for months at the Date field.

[image]

Comment: Do you want an example in Framework manager or using a reporting studio data item/filter definition?

Comment: @VAI Jason I am  using report studio.  I also want to prepare the data with data module and then to use them in a  Dashboard. I you also know how to do it through framework manager it is useful to know it.

Answer (score 0):

Year over year

Can you build a data item like this?  Example uses [Sales] as the metric you want conditioned.

```
IF ([Work Date] between date(extract(year,[Target Date]) || '-01-01')
and [Target Date]) then ([Sales])Else(0)
```

Comment: I want a calculation to do the Year over Year .Sth simple like the command in power bi.

Comment: Okay year over year, did you try the example above?

Comment: the expression above did not create the YoY  column for a meaure object in order to take the YoY column and display it through a crosstab on a dashboard.

Comment: You requested a filter.  Not a column/measure.  Can you give more information?  Do do you have access to Framework manager or this has to be done in the authoring studio.  What version of Cognos are you using?

Comment: Yes, in order to apply the YoY filter on a measure column and take the desired results. I want a filter like the filters on the FISCAL CALENDAR. I use Cognos Analytics 11.1

Comment: my question was updated. I cannot apply your filter because the **[work date]**  and the **[target date]** are in the same column  but in _different lines_.  Can you suggest anything else?

Comment: Clarify are you looking at more than two years of data at a time?

Comment: Yes, I  want YoY for  the last 4 years, at least.

Comment: Can you describe the columns or data items you need?
To express YoY for 19/18 how many columns?
To express YoY for 18/17 how many columns?
To express YoY from 19 to 17, how many columns?

I am trying to understand what the difference is between just listing each year of the metic vs a YoY comparison.  
Would a crosstab with years of data work?